# Mit oder ohne Artikel? Einwirkung auf die Umwelt vs. Einfluss auf Umwelt

Tags: article

Kann man das so sagen?

1. keine wesentliche Einwirkung auf -/die Umwelt haben
2. keinen wesentlichen Einfluss auf -/die Umwelt haben

Sollte man den Artikel vor 'Umwelt' setzen?

Der Kontext:

> Jugendliche haben keinen wesentlichen Einfluss auf die Umwelt.

Ich bin mir nicht sicher, ob ich den Artikel vor die Umwelt setzen soll, wenn es sich um eine allgemeine Bezeichnung handelt.

Comment: Willkommen bei German.SE. Was ist denn das Ziel der Aussage? Welchen Kontext gibt es? (or write in english if that fits better: what is intention of sentence, what context?

Comment: Jugendliche haben keinen wesentlichen Einfluss auf die Umwelt. Ich bin mir nicht sicher, ob ich den Artikel vor die Umwelt setzen soll, wenn es sich um eine allgemeine Bezeichnung handelt.

Comment: Bitte alle Ergänzungen in die Frage reineditieren. Kommentare können verlustig gehen.

Comment: @Taman: Du sollst den Artikel vor die Umwelt setzen wenn es denn ein wohlgeformter Satz sein soll. Sonst fehlt Artikel :-) Kein Artikel wird normalerweise bei Ortsnamen, Berufsbezeichnungen und Fähigkieten/Tätigkeiten.

Comment: Warum ? Man sagt doch z.B.: "Schule macht Kindern keinen Spaß". Der Satz hat eine allgemeine Bedeutung und hier wurden die Artikel weggelassen. Warum sollte ich das denn nicht so in diesem Fall machen?

Comment: Die Frage müßte andersrum lauten: warum hat die Schule keinen Artikel in dem Fall. Grundsätzlich wird für Substantive im deutschen ein Artikel verwendet. Punkt. Es gibt allerdings Ausnahmen und Ausnahmen von Ausnhamen. Die Schule würde ich da irgendwo zwischen Ortsangabe und Tätigkeit, versubstantiviertes Verb sehen.

Comment: Aber Schule und Umwelt sind beides Abstrakta. Ich verstehe es immer nicht.

Comment: Nein, das denke ich nicht. 1. Gibt es denn eine Regel, die ein Abstraktum generell vom Gebrauch des Artikels ausnimmt ? Doch im Allgemeinen nur, wenn es einen Zustand oder eine Eigenschaft benennt ? 2. "Die Umwelt" ist in der Tat etwas sehr Konkretes.

Answer (score 4):

In deinem Beispielsatz ist die Verwendung des Artikels (hier: "die") unumgänglich.

> Jugendliche haben keinen Einfluss auf die Umwelt

Der schulbuchmäßige Grund für die Verwendung des Artikels hier ist, dass die hier angesprochene Umwelt als - im gegebenen Kommunikationszusammenhang -  bekannt vorausgesetzt wird.

<sup>Dinge im grammatischen Singular, die nach gängiger Vorstellung nur einmal vorkommen (die Umwelt, das Weltall, die Liebe), werden in einer deutschsprachigen Kommunikationssituation standardmäßig als "den Kommunikationsteilnehmern bereits bekannt" vorausgesetzt, und daraus folgt, dass der bestimmte Artikel einzusetzen ist.</sup>

Eine Situation, in der der Artikel weggelassen werden könnte (weil es "irgend eine" Umwelt ist, über die auch bisher noch nicht gesprochen wurde), müsste man sich recht umständlich konstruieren. Mir fällt dazu jetzt leider nichts Brauchbares ein.

Man kann zwar durchaus sagen:

> Jugendliche haben keinen Einfluss auf Umwelt und Psychomotorik des Walfischs.

*Warum* man das hier so sagen kann, ist mir selber nicht ganz klar. Jedenfalls ist es ein wohlgeformter Satz in deutscher Sprache. Genauso wohlgeformt wäre aber auch:

> Jugendliche haben keinen Einfluss auf die Umwelt und die Psychomotorik des Walfischs.

Vermutung: Es ist akzeptiert, den Artikel in solchen Fällen wegzulassen, weil der Satz sonst zu umständlich würde. Hier hätte also einfach die Gewöhnung der Sprechergemeinschaft eingesetzt. - Denn eine Argumentation im Sinne von "In diesem Fall wird die Umwelt als nicht-bereits-thematisiert vorausgesetzt" halte ich für zu weit hergeholt.

Wenn man nun weiterexperimentiert:

> Autoren haben Einfluss auf Einsatz des bestimmten Artikels.
>
> Autoren haben Einfluss auf den Einsatz des bestimmten Artikels.

Hier würde ich sagen: Der zweite Satz - mit Artikel - ist komplett okay. Der erste - ohne Artikel - ist, jedenfalls in normalem Fließtext (im Gegensatz zu Überschriften), etwas holprig. Unbestreitbar wohlgeformt wäre er aber in der Form:

> Autoren haben Einfluss auf Einsatz und Auslassung des bestimmten Artikels.

Hier kann man den Artikel wieder problemlos weglassen. Ja, es wäre geradezu seltsam, hier "*auf den Einsatz und die Auslassung*" zu schreiben.

Das bestätigt mich in dem Eindruck, dass das Weglassen dann um so eher akzeptabel wird, je mehr die zu beartikelnden Substantive **Teil einer Aufzählung** sind. Also:

> Jugendliche haben keinen Einfluss auf Umwelt, Sexualverhalten, Psychomotorik, Schwanzlänge und Flossenschlagfrequenz des Walfischs.

Das ist jetzt aber nur eine ad hoc gebildete Hypothese.

Comment: Alle wissen doch ebenfalls, was die Schule ist, und wie sie aussieht. Warum kann man dann sagen: Schule macht Kindern keinen Spaß. Das ist auch eine Tatsache, die eher bekannt ist.

Comment: @Taman ich würde sagen, dass es hier tatsächlich um eine ganz bestimmte Umwelt geht (nämlich die der Menschheit), während in deinem Beispiel *keine* bestimmte Schule gemeint ist, sondern jede beliebige Form von Schule.

Comment: Umwelt bezieht sich m.E. meist auf eine räumlich und zeitlich aber meist sehr unscharf begrenzte Umwelt. Allerdings gibt es Jugendliche epochenübergreifend und weltweit seit es Menschen gibt, auch wenn es das Konzept nicht immer gab. "Josefine und Paul in Meppen haben keinen Einfluss auf die/ihre/meine Umwelt." Es gibt sehr wohl viele Umwelten.

Comment: @userunkown Du selber hast aber den Artikel im ersten Satz weggelassen. Warum denn?

Comment: +1, auch die Hypothese klingt in meinen Ohren sehr schlüssig. Ich würde es in meinem Sprachgebrauch ebenso handhaben.