# Unterschied zwischen »sich Wissen aneignen« and »sich das Wissen aneignen«

Tags: difference, article

> sich Wissen aneignen

oder

> sich **das** Wissen aneignen

Was ist der Unterschied zwischen den beiden Ausdrücken?

Comment: Beides kann richtig sein, je nach Kontext würde man die eine oder andere Version wählen.

Comment: Vielleicht schreibe ich allgemein zu lange Sätze. Ich finde dennoch eine Frage wesentlich verständlicher, falls sie mehr als das eine fragliche Wort enthält. Insbesondere weil auch fehlt, wieso weshalb warum in welchem Kontext die Frage auftaucht und worin das Problem gesehen wird/wo die eigene Unsicherheit besteht.  Ebenfalls ist der Titel sehr generisch und hätte auch diese Frage sein können https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/58292/mit-oder-ohne-artikel-einwirkung-auf-die-umwelt-vs-einfluss-auf-umwelt

Comment: Die downvoter dürfen mal eine Antwort versuchen. Ist gar nicht mal trivial.

Comment: Im Nachsatz wird nach 2 Sätzen gefragt, aber gezeigt wurden nur Fragmente. Der Unterschied ist das "das". Es gibt also einen spezifischen Kontext, aus dem sich ergibt, welches Wissen angeeignet.

Answer (score 6):

Kommt auf den Kontext an. Im Allgemeinen bedeutet *sich Wissen aneignen* soviel wie *etwas dazulernen*, ohne das Gelernte näher zu bestimmen. Es kann auch bedeuten, sich Wissen oder Fähigkeiten auf einem Gebiet *zum Teil* anzueignen.

> Er hat nicht nur faul rumgesessen, sondern sich Wissen angeeignet. (Beispiel von *user unknown*)
>
> Er hat sich Wissen über den Gebrauch der Artikel im Deutschen angeeignet (aber beherrscht ihn noch nicht ganz).

*Sich **das** Wissen aneignen* bedeutet hingegen, sich Information aus einem abgegrenzten Bereich zu verschaffen, meist zu der Lösung einer bestimmten Aufgabe oder eines bestimmten Problems. Ein Beispiel:

> Er hat sich das Wissen über den Gebrauch der Artikel im Deutschen angeeignet (und beherrscht ihn jetzt).

Comment: In was für einem/welchem Kontext könnte man vor dieser Redewendung den Artikel weglassen?

Comment: Man kann ihn weglassen wenn die Sache nicht spezifiert ist. "Sich generelles Wissen aneignen". Man kann den Artikel benutzen oder weglassen, wenn das Wissen spezifiert ist. "Sich (das) Wissen über die Verwendung der deutschen Sprache aneignen".

Comment: Könntest du mir bitte ein Beispiel geben?

Comment: Der bestimmte Artikel funktioniert wie ein Fingerzeig. Wie ein kleines Demonstrativpronomen.

Comment: @Janka Könntest du mir bitte dann ein Beispiel geben?

Comment: @Taman Du hast doch schon zwei Beispiele die es erklären?

Comment: @Taman: Er hat nicht nur faul rumgesessen, sondern sich Wissen angeeignet.